# SQL Left Join Subquery Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm trying to get the most recent price from the data table. The data would come out like such:

> Part  Price   Date
>
> ----- -----   --------
>
> 10525  .25    1/1/2010
>
> 10525  5.00   7/6/2014
>
> 10526  4.25   7/1/2014

I tried to use a join so that I could get the result of "10525  5.00   7/6/2014", but it gives me this error:

> The column prefix 'orderdtl' does not match with a table name or alias name used in teh query. Statement(s) could not be prepared."

If I take the join out, it works just fine. Where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT orderdtl.partnum, orderdtl.docunitprice, orderhed.orderdate
FROM mfgsys80.dbo.orderdtl AS orderdtl, mfgsys80.dbo.orderhed AS orderhed
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT orderdtl.partnum, MAX(orderhed.orderdate) AS 'maxDate'
    FROM mfgsys80.dbo.orderdtl AS orderdtl, mfgsys80.dbo.orderhed AS orderhed
    GROUP BY orderdtl.partnum
) AS Temp
    ON orderdtl.partnum = Temp.partnum AND orderhed.orderdate = Temp.maxDate
WHERE orderdtl.ordernum = orderhed.ordernum AND ((orderdtl.custnum=74))
ORDER BY orderdtl.partnum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query formation is wrong. It should be like

```
SELECT orderdtl.partnum, orderdtl.docunitprice, orderhed.orderdate
FROM mfgsys80.dbo.orderdtl AS orderdtl
JOIN mfgsys80.dbo.orderhed AS orderhed
ON orderdtl.ordernum = orderhed.ordernum
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT ol.partnum, MAX(od.orderdate) AS 'maxDate'
    FROM mfgsys80.dbo.orderdtl ol 
    JOIN mfgsys80.dbo.orderhed od
    ON ol.ordernum = od.ordernum
    GROUP BY ol.partnum
) Temp
ON orderdtl.partnum = Temp.partnum 
AND orderhed.orderdate = Temp.maxDate
WHERE  orderdtl.custnum=74
ORDER BY orderdtl.partnum
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! My SQL is pretty rusty, but what you did makes sense now that I see it.